# Border around Image

Tags: php, image-manipulation, border, outline

I want to put border around regular size image using php. I m wondering that i found border for text to image but not for simple images. The border width may be changeable. Please help

Comment: are you planning on using PHP GD [http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php] or CSS manipulation?

Comment: What do you mean with: 'I m wondering that i found border for text to image but not for simple images.' Are you trying to use text as a border for an image? Also your question is quite poor in information, please supply more information on what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The img element has by default a border attribute http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_IMG.asp
Not a php expert but I would also opt for having a dynamic var inside of the tag itself so that it is fully flexible

Answer (score 20):

I would not manipulate the images using GD or imagemagick but instead put a [css border][1] on the image or a div behind the image that's slighly bigger than the image.

Either you put a border on every picture using css :

```
img { border: 2px solid #000; }
```

Or you can define some border classes likes this :

```
.border1 {border: 1px solid #000}
.border2 {border: 2px solid #000}
.border3 {border: 3px solid #000}
```

and then use on your images :

```
<img src="..." class="border1"></img>
```

or

```
<img src="..." class="border3 "></img>
```

**edit :** if you were using scss/sass you could even do something like :

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
   img.border_#{$i} { border: #{$i}px solid #000; }
}
```

Sass rocks !

About the colors :

```
.bMainColor{border-color:#ff0000;}
.bSecColor{border-color:#00ff00;}
.bThirdColor{border-color:#0000ff;}
```

and on the img tag :

```
<img src="..." class="border1 bMainColor"></img>
```

I guess there are so many ways to use css :)

References about borders :

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-properties

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/bordersoutlines

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Comment: Manipulating the images using GD uses a lot more ressources and if you ever want to redesign your site and change the border color your stuck processing all the images again ...

Comment: very well explained altough i would prefer creating a border class defining the border-style and color, and define the thinkness in the tag itself using inline styles. but its a question of style i think.

Comment: I tried to ameliorate it a bit to thank people for keeping voting for it :)

Answer (score 2):

Use ImageMagick in php , it has direct command to add border to images,
see

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#border

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to be changeable, make a textbox, where you enter the pixel size of the border
and then a submit button.. Use post or get, what ever you like..

BUT, this WILL only be working aslong as your not changing page, unless you make this dynamic somehow..

```
<img src="..." style="border:<? $_POST['pixel']; ?>" />
```

otherwise, use @dwarfy's solution..